# How to include a weighting function for a classificatioon of 1d plot?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, classification, weighted, feature-descriptor

I have a 1d curve that is extracted from an object in an image and I am describing this 1d curves using Fourier descriptors and afterwards classifying it using Bayesian classification. It outputs then some score discribing the shape of the object (described by the curve). It works fine. However, I would like now to include a weighting function such that regions have not the same impact on the score. For exampe, part 0%-20% of the length of the plot is assigned a weight of 0.2 and the rest has the same value as before so let's say 1. So if that region brings the score to a low value, that weighting should increase the score because now it has less impact.

How could I include the weighting functions such that it modifies the score accordingely and logically?

The descriptor might not necessarily be calculated from Fourier but might come from another procedure. Because I know that my weighting function is in the spatial domain and the descriptors are in the frequency domain. I have thought about calculating the scatter matrix but weighting the covariance would not really mean lowering/increasing the score accordingely.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The "weighting function" will be part of your classifier, and the exact method depends on what model you use (a Bayesian classifier is not specific enough). A simple example is once you have your Fourier descriptor - some complex vector - split the vector in half, and train each half on two different classifiers. Then you weight each classifier's prediction differently and combine them to get the final prediction. This is a crude ensemble model example. But if you are using SVMs or random forest, those will require different "weighting" approach.

Comment: @mimocha thank you for your response. But splitting the vector in half is working if I wanted to weight regions in the frequency domain. But I am looking for a way to weight in the spatial domain.

Comment: If you meant weighting parts of the image differently, then the simplest method would be cropping the image into multiple parts, then running Fourier descriptor + training classifiers individually on each part. But that is a pretty hacky way of doing it, which I can't recommend.

Comment: I think it would be best if you could share your code example so others can get a sense of what you've done so far. Right now I'm not even sure if I am thinking of the same concepts you are describing or not. Terms like "1D curve" is too vague and can be represented (programmatically) in different ways - which affects what algorithms work best for your usecase.